# Creating a custom UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to have a custom view for `UIActivityIndicatorView` rather than relying on options given by iOS. How can I create my own view here?

I have a list of images with me to create a animated view.

Comment: Check this link : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/07/custom-activityindicator.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you haven't specified the case in which you want to use the activity indicator,

check the below tutorial blog for custom `UIActivityIndicatorView`,

Custom UIActivityIndicatorView (EDIT: This link is gone)

[Showing a "Loading..." message over the iPhone keyboard](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html)

Comment: I have a set of images which I want to animate instead of regular spinner in loading overlay.

Answer (score 3):

This is implementation of [custom UIActivityIndicator](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ddindicator) from scratch ready for integrating.

Answer (score 0):

Abhinav, if you want to use a set of images you could as well use a `UIImageView`. Set the `animationImages` and start-stop as you wish.

Answer (score -2):

[This](https://github.com/Sopan/SSLoadingOverlay) one looks nice and clean, can be hooked to the code easily too.