# Custom Activity Indicator

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, activity-indicator

I'm looking for a custom Activity Indicator for iOS which should look and work like on Facebook app (for iPhone) while loading images. Has anyone found such custom component?

Comment: Surely if it's custom, you make it yourself?

Comment: there are many such components available. Quick search in google lead me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010237/creating-a-custom-uiactivityindicatorview

Comment: This website has lots of custom controls for iOS. Including several activity indicators http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls

Comment: I like SpinKit, easy to implement and looks nice on iOS http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/spinkit/